# node.js node-notifier permission error

Tags: node.js, permissions, npm

I am currently working on a node.js application. For OSX, I am using the [node-notifier](https://github.com/mikaelbr/node-notifier) module to display native notifications. Here is a small snippet of code:

```
notification.notify({
  title: title,
  subtitle: subtitle,
  message: message
}, function(err, data) {
  Logger.info('err:', err);
  Logger.info('data:', data);
});
```

This works beautifully in development, but as soon as I package the application and deploy it, I receive this error every time a notification is to be displayed:

**killed=false, code=126, signal=null**

I realize this is a permission error, but am stumped as to why the behaviour is different in prod/dev.

If anyone has any suggestions or experience with this module I would appreciate any feedback.

Comment: maybe depends on domain... localhost scripts usualy have full permission, dedicated scripts are not trusted